# Adding locale to the Braintree to hosted fields

Tags: braintree, 3d-secure, braintree-javascript

I am trying to add locale to the Braintree hosted fields so that I get the challenge window on spanish.
I tried adding it to the  hostedFields as shown below.

```
window.braintree.hostedFields.create({
      authorization: clientToken,
      locale: 'es_ES',
})
```

But I am still getting the challenge window in english.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge window is in an iframe that's [hosted](https://github.com/braintree/braintree-web/blob/main/src/three-d-secure/internal/bank-frame.html#L70) by the cardholder's issuing bank, their bank determines the language to be displayed. It's entirely out of the Drop-In SDK's control.

In sandbox, test card challenge windows are owned by Braintree's MPI provider, CardinalCommerce, and also cannot be altered.